# Issue with mapping using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

so this is my code here:

```
library(lubridate)

COVID <- COVID %>% mutate(Date = ymd(COVID$dateRep))


ggplot(data = COVID, aes(x=Date, y=cases))+ geom_point()

ggplot(data = COVID, aes(x=Date, y=cases))+ geom_point(aes(color=countriesAndTerritories))
```

Here I just have the colors mapped to countries but my plot wont show:

[image]

Here my plot shows but without the labels

[image]

my overall plan is to show if cases per day increases around holidays (times of travel)

Comment: It looks like you have over a hundred `countriesAndTerritories`, so many that your legend it taking up the whole plot. There are many ways you could deal with this: you could make a bigger plot area, make your legend text smaller, hide your legend, subset your graph to look at a subset at a time, aggregate your groups, highlight a few series of interest and leave the rest unlabeled, etc.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try ymd(dateRep) instead of ymd(COVID$dateRep). Sorry I don't have my computer in front of me at the moment, but this is the only thing that jumps out to me at a glance.